# Return saved entity with @ManyToOne relationship after POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with an entity called `Person`, which has a `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
    // ...
}
```

The `PersonController` is used to allow to `GET` existing persons and `POST` new ones:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(final PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/person/{personId}")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable long personId) {
        return personRepository.findById(personId).get();
    }

    @PostMapping("/person_save_and_return_by_id")
    public Person personSaveAndReturnById(@RequestBody Person person) {
        Person savedPerson = personRepository.save(person);
        // the payload sent by the client does not necessarily include all
        // properties of the Country class, it might contain just the id.
        // Therefore, we fetch the person from the database, so that all
        // necessary JOIN operations are made and no properties are set to null.
        Person samePerson = personRepository.findById(savedPerson.getId()).get();
        return samePerson;
    }
}
```

I would like to `POST` new persons without having to describe the existing `Country` in its entirety, I only want to denote its id:

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"firstName": "Frodo", "lastName": "Baggins", "country": {"id": 1}}' http://localhost:8080/person_save_and_return_by_id
```

Unfortunately, the returned entity has all country properties, except for the id, set to null:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Frodo",
   "id" : 4,
   "lastName" : "Baggins",
   "country" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "description" : null,
      "countryCodeIso" : null
   }
}
```

The POST request inserts everything into the database as it should. For instance, if I `GET` the object I just previously posted:

```sh
curl -i  http://localhost:8080/person/4
```

The returned json looks exactly as it should:

```
{
   "lastName" : "Baggins",
   "firstName" : "Frodo",
   "country" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "countryCodeIso" : "FR",
      "description" : "France"
   },
   "id" : 4
}
```

But that doesn't help me, because I need to access the `Country` instance in the same method where the new `Person` is created.

My question is, why does the newly created person have a country with some properties set to null in the `@PostMapping` method, when the exact same person does not have those null values in the `@GetMapping` called right after? How can I access the person's country correctly during the `@PostMapping`, without resorting to workarounds such as explicitly fetching the country via its id?

The code is also available on [github](https://github.com/nroi/gs-accessing-data-rest/tree/master/complete). It uses the h2database, but I have the same issue with hibernate and postgresql. Notice that two countries are inserted during startup, so no foreign key violations are thrown when the country id is set to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: hello.Country`. I just want to be able to refer to existing country ids.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch only country from the repository given the country_id you provide in the payload. Then set the whole country object to Person and save person.

Comment: Fetching the country is not required just for saving the person, because the entity is persisted correctly. Fetching the country from the given id to access the country properties would work, but I still don't understand why I can't access the country via the person in the `@PostMapping` without having null values.

Comment: Maybe some fetchType is for that puropose? But it's just a guess for me.

Comment: neither `FetchType.EAGER` nor `FetchType.LAZY` work.